# How to store structured square grid data suitable for paraview?

Tags: paraview

I have some data like this

```
i  j  Rho  ux   vy
1  1  1.0  0    1.5
2  1  1.0  0.1  1
...
```

These numbers are center of cells coordinates (i and j) and other property values of that cell. 
all cells are in the same size and are square. 
how can I save my data so it can be read by Paraview?
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be the following

- Read you dataset as a table assuming it is a csv file.
- Add a TableToPoints filter and set the I and J correctly.
- Add a ResampleWithImageData filter to generate cells around the points.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could develop a ParaView writer converting your data into a VTK compatible format. Regarding the kind of cells you have, I suggest the `.vti` format specialized for [`vtkImageData`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageData.html) for example.

The first step would be to transform the coordinates of center of cells into coordinates of points. Assuming `s` is the size of the cell and `(i,j)` the coordinates of its center :

```
// using d for visiblity
d = s/2

// the embedding is in the plane, the value of z is arbitrary
z = 0

// list of points for one cell
p0 = (i-d, j-d, z)
p1 = (i-d, j+d, z)
p2 = (i+d, j-d, z)
p3 = (i+d, j+d, z)
```

I used pseudo-code as you did not specify a language in particular. With this transformation, keep in mind that you should avoid duplicated points as connected cells shared common points.

Then the second step is to add the property values as scalar or vector fields (see [vtkDataArray](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataArray.html)) associated on the cells (see [vtkCellData](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCellData.html)).